# How to add a CSS class to an render array?

Tags: 7, theming

In a template file, before `print render($content['field_image']);` I would like to add a CSS class to the image in the `$content['field_image']` render array. How can I do this?
Here is the render array:

```
Array
(
[#theme] => field
[#weight] => 2
[#title] => Image
[#access] => 1
[#label_display] => hidden
[#view_mode] => full
[#language] => und
[#field_name] => field_image
[#field_type] => image
[#field_translatable] => 1
[#entity_type] => node
[#bundle] => ll_basic_page
[#object] => stdClass Object
[#items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fid] => 6777
                [alt] => alt text
                [title] => 
                [uid] => 1
                [filename] => imageFile.jpg
                [uri] => public://imageFile.jpg
                [filemime] => image/jpeg
                [filesize] => 28742
                [status] => 1
                [timestamp] => 1314312382
                [rdf_mapping] => Array
                    (
                    )
            )
    )
[#formatter] => image
[0] => Array
    (
        [#theme] => image_formatter
        [#item] => Array
            (
                [fid] => 6777
                [alt] => alt text
                [title] => 
                [uid] => 1
                [filename] => imageFile.jpg
                [uri] => public://imageFile.jpg
                [filemime] => image/jpeg
                [filesize] => 28742
                [status] => 1
                [timestamp] => 1314312382
                [rdf_mapping] => Array ()
            )
        [#image_style] => 
        [#path] => 
    )
)
```

And this is the HTML output:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-image field-type-image field-label-hidden" thmr="thmr_96">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">
      <span thmr="thmr_97">
        <span thmr="thmr_98">
          <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://..../sites/default/files/imageFile.jpg" alt="alt text" />
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding a class to `$content['field_image']['#attributes']['class']`, but that didn't work.
Do you have any idea on how I can achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 7):

I believe it would be:

```
$content['field_image'][0]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my-class';
```

Or to assign it to every element,

```
foreach (element_children($content['field_image'] as $key) {
  $content['field_image'][$key]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my-class';
}
```

Comment: Tried this but doesn't work.

Comment: Which part? The first or the second? Because both actually work.

Answer (score 4):

The above solutions did not work for me (and weren't clearly described in any case). Here's the way I solved this exact problem. This is probably not the best way, and certainly not the only, but it's a valid "Drupal way" and works. Open up the **template.php** file for your template.

Paste in the following function, which you will have to MODIFY and customize for your usage scenario. For example, you must replace `<TEMPLATENAME>` with your template name, and add or subtract classes as desired, and other things, as you'll see.

```
function <TEMPLATENAME>_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
    // If this image is of the type 'Staff Photo' then assign additional classes to it:
    if ($variables['style_name'] == 'staff_photo') {
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'lightbox';
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'wideborder';
    }
}
```

I created an "if" statement to determine when the class should be added to the image, but you will have to customize that however you like--you might eliminate it entirely if you want a class on ALL image-field images, or you might say `if (drupal_is_front_page())` if you only want it applied on the front page, etc.

In MY case, I created an image style (Configuration > Media > Image Styles) for Staff Photos and added the if clause to only apply my preferred classes to images of that specified Image Style. I think that's a great way to do it, but you can do what you like.

Now, whenever I am viewing a node which contains an image-field with image style of "Staff Photo," the classes magically appear in the IMG tag, which is just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

This issue seems fixed in core 7.23

In the node tpl add this at the top:

```
<?php
$content['field_name'][0]['#item']['attributes']['class'][] = 'your-class';
?>
```

Comment: This works for field_type=image.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this:

```
  $array['container']['#prefix'] = '<div id = "container">';
  $array['container']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

Comment: In this case, you'd be better off with `'#type' => 'container'` and the `#attributes` method above, rather than hardcoding the div and class, because then nothing can add to the class, defeating the purpose of a renderable array.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you in a "field--field-image.tpl.php," use this:

```
$item['#item']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'your-class';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution, but for styling a form input element and not an image.
Inside my customized commerce_coupon.checkout_pane.inc include i added an #attributes array containing the necessary classes.

So if you're looking for a module entangled solution instead of template embedded, this might be a good alternative.

Running on Drupal 7.39

```
  $pane_form['coupon_add'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',   
    '#value' => t('Add coupon'),    
    '#name' => 'coupon_add',    
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),    
    '#ajax' => array(    
      'callback' => 'commerce_coupon_add_coupon_callback',    
      'wrapper' => 'commerce-checkout-coupon-ajax-wrapper',    
    ),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('btn', 'btn-13')),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need some conditions to apply the class, you'll need to gather page fields informations.

You can do it with function `template_preprocess_field(&$variables)`.

```
template_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_type'] == 'image') {
        $variables['items'][0]['#item']['attributes']['class'][] = 'your-class';
  }
}
```